# ошибка Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-cursor

Этот метод вызывается с ошибкой:

```
  try {
  mMainListView.onItemClickListener = OnItemClickListener { 
   adapter, itemClicked, position, arg3 ->
                        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, CurrentSetActivity::class.java)
                        intent.putExtra("SET", mainCursor?.getString(mainCursor!!.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_SHORTNAME)))
                        startActivity(intent)
                    }
  } catch (t: Throwable) {Log.e(TAG,t.toString()}
```

Ошибка:

```
06-25 12:25:08.435 22534-22534/com.arity.android.mtglibver2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.arity.android.mtglibver2, PID: 22534
android.database.StaleDataException: Attempting to access a closed CursorWindow.Most probable cause: cursor is deactivated prior to calling this method.
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:160)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:65)
    at com.arity.android.mtglibver2.CardsListActivity$onResume$1.onItemClick(CardsListActivity.kt:176)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:315)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1269)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3375)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4383)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5936)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:958)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:819)
```

Ошибка эта начинает вылетать только после фильтрации ListView с помощью EditText(подозреваю,что из-за обновления списка курсор становится закрытым):

```
   //установка слушателя изменения текста
                mMainFilter.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                    override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    }

                    override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                    }

                    //при изменении текста выполняем фильтрацию
                    override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                        mainAdapter!!.filter.filter(s.toString())
                    }
                })

                //устанавливаем провайдер фильтрации
                mainAdapter!!.setFilterQueryProvider({ constraint ->
                    if (constraint == null || constraint.isEmpty()) {
                        db!!.rawQuery("select * from " + DataBaseHelper.TABLE_OTHER_CAT, null)
                    } else {
                        db!!.rawQuery("select * from " + DataBaseHelper.TABLE_OTHER_CAT + " where " +
                                DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + " like ?", arrayOf("%" + constraint.toString() + "%"))
                    }
                })
```

Вопрос заключается в следующем: Как,собственно, избавиться от этой ошибки?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Избавьтесь вот от этого:

```
intent.putExtra("SET", mainCursor?.getString(mainCursor!!.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DataBaseHelper.COLUMN_SHORTNAME)))
```

Курсор в этот момент уже мертв (закрыт) и читать из него больше нельзя.
Позаботьтесь чтобы в этом месте уже было значение из БД, а не ссылка на курсор.

Comment: А можно ли как-то оживить курсор после фильтрации списка?

Comment: @ArDDuino, если я правильно понял и Вы используете `SimpleCursorAdapter`, то его метод `getItem()` вернёт живой курсор, причём сразу на указанной позиции.